# how end certificate refers to intermediate certificate

Tags: certificates, trust

As far as i know certificate chain is accomplished based on the issuer's CA name. It is possible that the algorithm to create certificate chain first reads end-certificate's issuer area and get the value of CA. Then make a search in trust store with this data, it reads the subject ares's CA value for all certificates. If there is a matching, algorithm accepts that certificate as a certificate in the chain.

At this point i wonder that; what if there is another certificate whose subject CA name is similar.
Here are my questions:

How the algorithm choose the suitable one?

Is there any reference except than the issuers' CA name to the certificate in chain?

Briefly how certificate chain accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I once wrote a program which validated the certificate chain of a signed PDF document. All certificates below the CA get validated by checking the signature. I think this is enough but you can check other fields for their sanity. Then you have to check if the root CA is in your trusted store. You should compare the subject (name) and fingerprint but it's also possible to compare the public key.

Answer (score 1):

Chain building is a multi-step process which involves a lot of operations.

`Subject` and `Issuer` pair is used only to bind certificates in temporary chains. Certificate chaining engine attempts to build as many chains as it can. After a set of chains is built, all chains are validated according to rules described in [RFC 5280 §6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6.1). During this process a tighter binding is performed using other fields (`Subject Key Identifier` and `Authority Key Identifier`) and signature validation. Any invalid chain is eliminated. In the end, certificate chaining engine gets single and best (among others) chain with its status.

I have a blog post which describes how CCE works in general: [Certificate Chaining Engine — how it works](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/certificate-chaining-engine-how-this-works.aspx)